# How to have Windows 8 Surface tablet warn low battery?

Tags: windows-8, windows-rt, microsoft-surface

While I use Windows 8 Surface tablet, the device will shut down at 6% battery, but never warns of low battery. Can I enable a setting that will warn me of low battery while in an app?

**Edit**

Changing power options has not helped thus far.

**Edit**

It looks like this is not a new problem:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfwinrt-surfusing/displaying-a-popup-when-battery-is-low/8df16bcc-464c-44a2-8b81-20efef44ed47?page=1

Still digging for a working solution.

Comment: Did you check under the **Power Option>Change plan setting>change advanced settings** and then at the botom **Battery** option?

Comment: If you have not any problem then you can try to give a "Reset" or "Refresh" to your surface. May be it can fix the problem.

Comment: @avirk, yes, I tried that one.

Comment: And it didn't fix the problem?

Comment: Correct, it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Try with a custom power plan and see what is the result?

Comment: I will give that a try.

Comment: Do it soon only 12 hrs left. lol :P

Comment: Sorry, was on a cruise. Something seems to have fixed it, as it warned of low battery tonight. Didn't try custom plan. Confusing.

Comment: Well, no need to sorry I was joking about the time. But I'm also surprised what did fix it?  It would be very handy for future readers to resolve the problem if you can track out the solution.

Answer (score 4):

Windows RT comes with one power plan: balanced. You can of course change these by going to Power options (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> to search for it). You'll want to mess with the Battery options.

[image]

[More information](http://www.winsupersite.com/article/windows8/surface-windows-rt-unboxing-day-notes-144647#/0)

Comment: Interesting, my low battery notification is set to on.

Comment: What is your low battery action? They both happen at the same time, so if it's set to anything but `Do nothing` you won't get the notification.

Comment: Low battery action is Do Nothing.

Answer (score 1):

By default the low battery level is 6%, which is too low. I set mine to 12% to solve this problem.

See if that works for you.